# How can I get checkboxlist currently selected item value

Tags: jquery, checkboxlist

I have a checkboxlist.After when I checked an item on it I will get the selected item value(not all of the selected items values,only the which I'm slected now),How can I do it in jquery.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" Enabled="False">
        <asp:listitem value="1"></asp:listitem>
        <asp:listitem value="2"></asp:listitem>
        <asp:listitem value="3"></asp:listitem>
        <asp:listitem value="4"></asp:listitem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can register a click event handler for all the checkboxes, inside the event handler `this` will point to the clicked checkbox

if jQuery >= 1.7

```
$('#CheckBoxList1').on('click', ':checkbox', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // handle checkbox check
        alert($(this).val());
    } else {
        // checkbox is unchecked
        alert('unchecked')
    }
});
```

if jQuery < 1.7

```
$('#CheckBoxList1 :checkbox').live('click', function() {
    alert($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Comment: @SelçukluEbrar jquery version used

Comment: I was looking for a solution on this and this was the best answer came across.

Answer (score 0):

This will display the value of the checkbox onclick:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: it isn't work,but it works with Arun P Johny's answer,I'm sorry I took your time,thank for your idea