# How to get the selected values from MVC CheckBoxFor jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-selectors

I am working on a MVC app and right now I am stuck on the following problem: I have checkboxes generated from one of my models, however I don't know how to get the value(either name of id) of the selected ones in javascript. Any ideas ?

Here's the code:

```
@if (Model.Controls.Any())
       {

           for (int x = 0; x < Model.Controls.Count(); x++)
           {
        <div aria-autocomplete="inline">

            @Html.CheckBoxFor(p => p.Controls[x].IsSelected, new { @class = "CCB" })
            @Html.Label(Model.Controls[x].Name)
            @Html.HiddenFor(p => p.Controls[x].ID)

        </div>
           }

       }
```

Working with :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.CCB').change(function (event) {
        var matches = [];
        $(".CCB:checked").each(function () {
            matches.push(this.value);
        });
        alert(matches);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.CCB').change(function (event) {
        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            var theId = $(this).attr('id'); // The id of the checkbox
            var theValue = $(this).val(); // The value field of the checkbox
        }
    });
});
```

See also [How can I get checkboxlist currently selected item value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142535/how-can-i-get-checkboxlist-currently-selected-item-value).